# can grow field object not working in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am working with crystal report in visual studio , the report contains data  from the data base . the Problem is that the field object height in the report  it is fine for short text length but  for  long text  some characters that exceed  the field object   height will be hidden.
 I have been used can grow property by checking it in the format object  window but it didn't work  the section height didn't increase automatically to wrap all text .

please how can i solve this problem ? any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: does it at least grow somewhat? like is it growing more than 1 line?

Comment: @DouglasTimms   it doesn't grow at all

Comment: here's a shot in the dark: try the advice on the last comment on this page: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3446761

Comment: @DouglasTimms thanks for your time and help , i dont know how to do that ( enter the string into a formula. Than place the formula into a text object.) Since  i am new in crystal report and i bring data from the DB by stored procedure . Can you help me more Please ?

Comment: in crystal reports, create a new formula. (it can be done by right-mouse clicking on Formular Fields in the "Field Explorer". In this formula field, drag and drop the notes field so the formula would look something like this {Command.Notes} or {TableName.Notes}.  Then back in your report, right mouse click in the Details section and select Insert --> Text Object. Then drag and drop that newly created Formula field into the newly created blank text object.

Comment: @DouglasTimms Thanks a lot  its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crystal reports, create a new formula. (it can be done by right-mouse clicking on Formular Fields in the "Field Explorer". In this formula field, drag and drop the notes field so the formula would look something like this {Command.Notes} or {TableName.Notes}. Then back in your report, right mouse click in the Details section and select Insert --> Text Object. Then drag and drop that newly created Formula field into the newly created blank text object.